# Cannot change ownership of a Samba shared NTFS drive

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, ntfs

I'm new to this so I'll be verbose.

I am setting up a headless NUC as a home server. Plugged in a 4TB NTFS external drive and it got automunted(?) under `/media/username/Seagate`. First step was sharing the drive on the network with my other devices (in the options the GUI offered me to download the samba server, I just had to tick a few checkboxes).

Next, I installed Jellyfin. I would like my media library to be on this samba shared (but for the server, still locally plugged in) drive. The problem is with the permissions. The entire disk is owned by `username:username` and I can't seem to do anything about it. Tried changing user, group, adding `jellyfin` to the `username` group, creating new group with both `username` and `jellyfin` in it and assigning that, nothing makes a dent, it always just shows `username:username`.

```
sudo chown -R jellyfin:jellyfin /media/username/Seagate
sudo chown -R username:jellyfin /media/username/Seagate
sudo chown -R :jellyfin /media/username/Seagate
sudo chown -R jellyfin /media/username/Seagate
sudo usermod -a -G username jellyfin
echo etc
```

Although handing it over to only `jellyfin` would probably be not the right solution, since I'd like the samba share to continue working. Ubuntu 22.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you never will. Microsoft filesystem do not understand POSIX. And `chmod`, `chown` are POSIX.

NTFS permissions are set when mounting. Samba has options for permissions in its configuration file [smb.conf](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)

It will look something like this:

```
[{share}]
path = /{path}
valid users = {users}
force group = {group}
read only = no
create mask = 0664
force directory mode = 2775
```

- the create mask: when creating a file it will be rw (owner), rw (group), r (other) and owned by {user} and set to group {group}
- dirs are rwx (owner), rwx (group), rw (other)
- try to avoid setting the "other" part of the permissions; I would suggest to keep it at `0`. That ALSO will help identify misconfigurations: if something does not work due to permissions it will be about the "user" and "group" for that user (better to have a person not have access that needs it than have one person have access that should not have it; the 1st you can fix; the 2nd you never get notified about and would require you yourself to check logs and configs to figure out that is the case).

There are a lot more options. See your `smb.conf` for more of these.

Another often use setup is the "public share" where everyone has access. If you want that replace `valid users = {users}` with `guest ok = yes`

All items between braces need to be replaced with what you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but I am still missing the big picture. If I have this config, then the jellyfin server should be able to access the mounted files? For now I am trying the (I suppose) easier `guest ok = yes` version, but no success.

Comment: One place where my explanation could have caused confusion is that jellyfin is on the same machine where the drive is mounted, so the jellyfin media library needs to just normally access the files by path, not through Samba. The samba share is for other PCs.

Comment: "NTFS permissions are set when mounting. " so set user and group where you mount it